# Tkinter dynamically create widgets from button

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm attempting to make a dynamic GUI where clicking a button causes the creation of a new frame that is placed above the button with 3 entry widgets (user options) inside of it, and I need to be able to read the user input from the 3 entry widgets & possibly alter them. Each time the button is pressed, three new callable entry widgets should appear.

I know that this is wrong because it has been giving me errors, but could something similar to the lists be used to create the widgets dynamically?

```
from Tkinter import *

app = Tk()

frameNames = []
widgetNames = []

def createwidgets():
    global widgetNames
    global frameNames
    frameNames += (str("g"+str(len(frameNames))))  #why does the letter & number get added as seperate elements?
    widgetNames += [(str("w"+str(len(widgetNames)-1))), 
                    (str("w"+str(len(widgetNames)))),    
                    (str("w"+str(len(widgetNames)+1)))]

    frameNames[len(frameNames) - 1] = Frame(app)
    frameNames[len(frameNames) - 1].pack()

    widgetNames[len(widgetNames) - 3] = Entry(frameNames[len(frameNames) - 1])
    widgetNames[len(widgetNames) - 3].pack()
    widgetNames[len(widgetNames) - 2] = Entry(frameNames[len(frameNames - )- 1])
    widgetNames[len(widgetNames) - 2].pack()
    widgetNames[len(widgetNames) - 1] = Entry(frameNames[len(frameNames) - 1])
    widgetNames[len(widgetNames) - 1].pack()

createWidgetButton = Button(app, text="createWidgets", command=createwidgets())
createWidgetButton.grid(sticky=S)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: what is the error that you're getting?

Comment: @Bryan I fixed one issue since you have last seen the code, but it seems that it is going into an infinite loop and not displaying the application at the moment which I do not know if that is because of the attempt at making list created widgets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is these four lines of code:

```
frameNames[len(frameNames) - 1] = Frame(app)
frameNames[len(frameNames) - 1].pack()
...
createWidgetButton = Button(app, text="createWidgets", command=createwidgets())
createWidgetButton.grid(sticky=S)
```

You are creating both the frame and button as a child of `app`, but you are using `grid` for one and `pack` for the other. You must be consistent with all direct descendants of `app` - they must all use `pack` or they must all use `grid`.

The second problem is this line:

```
frameNames += (str("g"+str(len(frameNames))))  #why does the letter & number get added as seperate elements?
```

Here, `frameNames` is a list and you are trying to add it with a string. Adding is not the same as appending. You need to append the new name, or put the new name in a temporary list before adding it.

```
frameNames.append(str(...))
```

The third problem is this line:

```
createWidgetButton = Button(app, text="createWidgets", command=createwidgets())
```

The above is exactly the same as this:

```
result = createWidgets()
createWidgetButton = Button(app, text="createWidgets", command=result)
```

You must pass a *reference* to a function, not *call* the function. Change the line to this (notice the lack of parenthesis after `createWidgets`):

```
createWidgetButton = Button(app, text="createWidgets", command=createwidgets)
```

---

Unrelated to the problem, but your code would be *much* easier to read if you used temporary variables instead of repeating the pattern `(str("w"+str(len(widgetNames)-1)`. As written, your code is almost impossible to read. Also, you don't want to be storing widget *names*, you need to store the actual widgets themselves.

And finally, don't do a wildcard import. There is simply no good reason to do it.

Here is how I would rewrite your code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()

frames = []
widgets = []

def createwidgets():
    global widgetNames
    global frameNames

    frame = tk.Frame(app, borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
    frames.append(frame)

    frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

    for i in range(3):
        widget = tk.Entry(frame)
        widgets.append(widget)

        widget.pack(side="left")

createWidgetButton = tk.Button(app, text="createWidgets", command=createwidgets)
createWidgetButton.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively simple.

We can do this by creating a `Frame` widget but not packing it, filling it with whatever we need and then having a `Button` call the pack on the `Frame` widget.

Much like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.create = Button(self.root, text="Create", command=self.draw)
        self.create.pack(side="bottom")
        self.frame = Frame(self.root)
        self.entry1 = Entry(self.frame)
        self.entry2 = Entry(self.frame)
        self.entry3 = Entry(self.frame)
        self.entry1.pack()
        self.entry2.pack()
        self.entry3.pack()
        self.submit = Button(self.frame, text="Submit", command=self.command)
        self.submit.pack()
    def draw(self):
        self.frame.pack(side="top")
    def command(self):
        print(self.entry1.get())
        print(self.entry2.get())
        print(self.entry3.get())

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

If you need to add multiple of these forms you can do something like the below which makes use of anonymous functions (`lambda`) in order to have "self aware" buttons which "know" which frame they're in:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.frames = []
        self.entries = []
        self.count = 0
        self.root = root
        self.create = Button(self.root, text="Create", command=self.draw)
        self.create.pack(side="bottom")
    def draw(self):
        self.frames.append(Frame(self.root, borderwidth=1, relief="solid"))
        self.frames[self.count].pack(side="top")
        self.entries.append([Entry(self.frames[self.count]), Entry(self.frames[self.count]), Entry(self.frames[self.count])])
        for i in self.entries[self.count]:
            i.pack()
        Button(self.frames[self.count], text="Submit", command=lambda c=self.count: self.submit(c)).pack()
        self.count += 1
    def submit(self, c):
        for i in self.entries[c]:
            print(i.get())

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I need to be able to click the button multiple times with each new widget having a way of retrieving its data.

Comment: That wasn't in your initial question. I've provided a solution.

Comment: I realize that it may have not been entirely clear in my initial question that the button needed to be reusable.